# Spring AOP - aspect not working without xml configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

My intention is run the aspect before get message method in service. I don't want to use xml configuration, so I add (hopefully) necessary annotation. But, when I run my application, aspect doesen't work, and nothing happen. Can You explain me why?

**Service**

```
public interface Service {
  void getMessage();
}
```

**Service implementation**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  public void getMessage() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

**Aspect**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.aop.Service.getMessage())")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("AOP is working!!!");
    }
}
```

**Run**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class AopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(AopApplication.class, args);
        final Service bean = run.getBean(ServiceImpl.class);
        bean.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Output**
Only `Hello world`

Comment: Try `getBean(Service.class)` instead.

Comment: Still not working... is simple polimorphism. Mayen I use wrong annotation?

Comment: shouldn't the aspect be `@Before("execution(* com.example.aop.ServiceImpl.getMessage())")` ? see here https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Comment: What exactly do You mean?  I have same @Before value with own path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you have to add `@Component` annotation to `LoggingAspect` class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the pointcut expression syntax should be like this:

```
@Before("execution(void com.aop.service.Service+.getMessage(..))")
```

The `+` is used to apply the pointcut to subtypes (you can replace `void` with `*` too.